# how to use facebook login authentication in my cordova ionic android application

Tags: angularjs, facebook, cordova, ionic-framework

how to use facebook login authentication in my cordova ionic android application.I am  just add the official cordova plugin for android from `https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/`. I want to integrate this plugin in my app.also i have facebook appid and appname.

Comment: if you wanna try with different one have a look at this https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html......this will surely help to make a login with fb

Comment: hi, that url not working getting an 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this plugin Cordova-plugin-facebook4:

https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4

works like a charm on both android and iOS ionic apps